# Wrong exe icon in windows explorer when using resource file

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have an FMX application created in RAD studio 10.4 and have set the main icon in Project Options, Icons. I have also added 2 additional icons in the resource file using Resources and Images, which will be used by an installer to create file associations. All icons are 32x32 pixels. The main icon appears correctly in the application title bar but not in Windows explorer. It always takes the first of the 2 additional icons in the resource file. At first I thought this could be due to windows caching of icons but it is not. I'm using software called icofx to extract the icons from the exe and I see that the main icon always appears last.

I have tried changing the identifiers in Resources and images with the same result. The identifiers shown in icofx are not the ones I set. I've also tried renaming the additional icons so that they're last alphabetically, but that doesn't work either.

If I try the same with an old Delphi 7 project then it always results in the main application icon appearing first, which is what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the other icons also available in the different formats (16x16, 32x32, etc)

Comment: All icons are 32x32 only.

Answer (score 1):

I have now resolved the issue by changing the identifiers of the additional icons so that they come after MAINICON alphabetically. The default is Icon_1, Icon_2, which come before MAINICON alphabetically. Changing them to ZIcon_1 and ZIcon_2 resolves the issue so that Windows Explorer takes MAINICON first.